# Nginx "No input file specified." in a dynamic folder subdomain setup

Tags: php, nginx, dns, subdomain, directory

Right, so I have this folder: /home/sites/dev/testphp/ inside this folder there's an index.php file, with a simple echo line. I also have a /home/sites/dev/testhtml/ with an index.html file.

When I visit http://testhtml.dev.ilun.no/ it works as expected.
But when I visit http://testphp.dev.ilun.no/ I simply get "No input file specified."

This is my config so far:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.ilun.no www.dev.ilun.no;
    root /home/sites/dev;
    index index.php index.html;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.*)\.dev.ilun\.no$;
    root /home/sites/dev/$1;
    index index.php index.html;
    if (!-d /home/sites/dev/$1) {
        rewrite . http://dev.ilun.no/ redirect;
    }
    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I'm completely stuck on this, and can't figure it out yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic root is tricky thing, try other regexp:

```
server_name  ~^(?P<subdomain>.+)\.dev.ilun\.no$;
root /home/sites/dev/$subdomain;
```

Comment: *Massive internet-hug to you*